# Cannot install harp.js on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, harp

I'm following some tutorials for webdevelopment, but I can't get **harp.js** installed on my Windows 10 pc, with **node.js** v11.10.0

Is it still possible to install harp.js, it fails with a lot of error messages.

I've tried with different node.js versions. Nothing  seems to work.

Hopefully, it is still possible to fix these error messages, without waiting for a newer version of harp..

Can I alter the dependecies to work with a newer version, without breaking everything else? Like for example the SASS dependecies which it tries to get from Github, but the link doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
$ npm install -g harp
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated classifier@0.1.0: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\harp -> C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\bin\harp

> node-sass@4.9.3 install C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-67_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-67_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs2\node.exe C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs2\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.10.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7.15
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 11.10.0
gyp verb command install [ '11.10.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "11.10.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 11.10.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 11.10.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64)
gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.Desktop
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17134
gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\deini\\.node-gyp\\11.10.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\deini\\.node-gyp\\11.10.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\deini\\.node-gyp\\11.10.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0
gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 24/02/2019 10:26:57.
Project "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
Project "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Release\obj\binding\".
  Creating directory "Release\obj\binding\binding.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Release\obj\binding\binding.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\include\node" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\src" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\deps\openssl\config" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\deps\openssl\openssl\include" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\deps\uv\include" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\deps\zlib" /I"C:\Users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\deps\v8\include" /I..\..\nan /Z7 /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /GL /D NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding /D USING_UV_SHARED=1 /D USING_V8_SHARED=1 /D V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1 /D WIN32 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 /D BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION /D _WINDLL /GF /Gm- /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR- /Fo"Release\obj\binding\\" /Fd"Release\obj\binding\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4800 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4244 /wd4267 /FC /errorReport:queue /Zc:threadSafeInit- ..\src\binding.cpp ..\src\create_string.cpp ..\src\custom_function_bridge.cpp ..\src\custom_importer_bridge.cpp ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp ..\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp ..\src\sass_types\error.cpp ..\src\sass_types\factory.cpp ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc"
  binding.cpp
  create_string.cpp
  custom_function_bridge.cpp
  custom_importer_bridge.cpp
  sass_context_wrapper.cpp
  boolean.cpp
  color.cpp
  error.cpp
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\create_string.cpp(17): warning C4996: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value': was declared deprecatedc:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\custom_function_bridge.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_function_bridge.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]

  c:\users\deini\.node-gyp\11.10.0\include\node\v8.h(2991): note: see declaration of 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value'
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  factory.cpp
  list.cpp
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\custom_importer_bridge.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/functions.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_importer_bridge.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_context_wrapper.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/context.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\binding.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  map.cpp
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_context_wrapper.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/context.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  null.cpp
  number.cpp
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\error.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  string.cpp
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\factory.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\factory.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\create_string.cpp(17): warning C4996: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value': was declared deprecatedc:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\custom_function_bridge.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_function_bridge.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\custom_importer_bridge.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/functions.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\custom_importer_bridge.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_context_wrapper.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/context.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\binding.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_context_wrapper.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/context.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\error.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\factory.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\factory.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\deini\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\src\sass_types\value.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sass/values.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp) [C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    12 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.17
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs2\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\deini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\harp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\harp\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\deini\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-24T09_27_03_212Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that Node.js and npm are up to date, to update Node.js use:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then to update npm use:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Then you can try and install harp.js again with `npm install -g harp`. 
If you run into issues with that then you can try:

```
npm uninstall -g harp
npm cache clear
npm install -g harp
```

However, the 404 is coming from something running in `scripts/install.js` and it tries to get something from this [Github](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-67_binding.node), which as you can see returns a 404, so you might need to find an alternative mirror.
Although you say you're using Node.js v11.10.0 but v4.9.3 of `node-sass` doesn't support that version(as you can see [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/v4.9.3)), just `0.10, 0.12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, so I suggest you uninstall your current version of node and reinstall the LTS this time(v10.15.1 as of now) instead of the current build.

Comment: I think installing v10.15.1 of Node solved this issue. Thanks for your quick solution.